# Changing font with uibutton and if else if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a UIlabel and IBAction
I am trying to switch a font back and forth using an if else statement by pressing the UIButton.

I have tried below
it will switch to the ArialRoundedMTBold but it wont switch back to helvetica.

```
if ( [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]) {
   [labelz1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:17.0]];
} else if ( [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:17.0]){

     [labelz1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]];

}
```

I also have tried

```
if ( labelz1.font ==[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]) {
    [labelz1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:17.0]];
} else if ( labelz1.font ==[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:17.0]){

    [labelz1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` effectively asks the question "Does HelveticaNeue 17pt exist?", the answer is yes, and so you set the label font to ArialRoundedMTBold 17pt. There is **no** connection between the `if` test and setting the label font – it doesn't matter what font you set the label to "Does HelveticaNeue 17pt exist?" will always have the same answer.

You need to ask the question "Is the font of the label `labelz1` HelveticaNeue 17pt?". To do that look at getting the label's font with `labelz1.font` and testing what font it is, for example:

```
UIFont *labFont = labelz1.font;
UIFont *f1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0];
if( [labFont isEqual:f1] ) ...
```

HTH